# Class 'Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-dusk

I updated composer using

`composer update`

having error

[image]

To resolve this i tried to do `composer require --dev laravel/dusk`

This is throwing

[image]

Any thing which i am missing ?

Please assist.

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? You need to register `Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider::class,` in providers array in `config/app.php` file

Comment: Laravel version 5.5.40

Comment: Have you added it?

Comment: I add this in app.php then composer dump-autoload that gave me `In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider' not found`

Comment: Try running this command: `composer dump-autoload -o`

Comment: Nothing changes error remains same as the last one

Comment: Please revert all changes and see this docs: https://www.sitepoint.com/laravel-dusk-intuitive-and-easy-browser-testing-for-all/ Hope it'll helps you!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168552/discussion-between-abdul-qadir-and-hiren-gohel).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you are using `Laravel 5.4` version you need to install `^2.0` of laravel dusk version.

Try this command to install it:

```
composer require --dev laravel/dusk:^2.0
```

Then add

```
Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider::class,
```

in `providers` array in `config/app.php` file.

This might be fixed your issue!

Comment: Yeah That fixed it. :)

Comment: Glad, i could help you :)

Comment: Thanks!
It's really necessary install dusk?

Comment: @Santee: Yes, after installing dusk, you can use the package!

Comment: If you don't want to use dusk, remove the ```Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider::class,``` line from config/app/php